# Could not update lightning components: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, id

I am using sublime and mavens mate combination. When I am trying to save an existing component, It is giving the following error: 
"Could not update lightning components: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined".

I tried to clean the project and tried to delete .lightning file config folder, but they ddnt work. Can anyone please suggest a workaround for this ?

Comment: **refresh the metadata index** and **update project** this will resolve your issue, this happens when we create a new component using MavensMate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, there are two ways to get this error:

1. You created your component using the Developer Console and after you refresh your metadata index and Update the project, then when you save any change the error shows.

   - To solve this error, you need to go to **config** folder and delete the **.lightning** file.
2. You created your component using Mavensmate, so when you try to save the error appears.

   - Here you only need to **Refresh** your metadata index and **Update** your Project.

For me was the first error and that's why I tried to sum it up in this post.
Hope this help.

Comment: Can you please explain where is .lightning file?